# The multi-part identifier could not be bound on join

Tags: sql

Can't figure out why I can't perform this join, I've done many like it in the past. Am I missing something?

```
SELECT *
FROM THB_View.PCM_PCM_BASE base
LEFT OUTER JOIN THB_View.PCM_PCM_BASE_REOCCUR rec
LEFT OUTER JOIN THB_View.ATV atv ON base.PCM_TAG = atv.ATV_OCCURRING_PCM_TAG
     ON base.RECORD_KEY = rec.RECORD_KEY
WHERE
    base.PCM_STATUS = 'ENROUTE'
    AND rec.PCM_HRC_TAG IS NULL OR rec.PCM_HRC_TAG = ''
    AND rec.PCM_EQP_TAG IS NULL OR rec.PCM_EQP_TAG = ''
```

The error occurs on `base.PCM_TAG` the 5th line in the SQL statement

Comment: you have multiple `on`s following eachother.

Comment: oh wow. I should have looked more carefully before posting. It's been a long day -_-

Comment: It should be `JOIN ... ON ... JOIN ... ON`, not `JOIN ... JOIN ... ON ... ON`.

Comment: @melpomene: Well, the `JOIN ... JOIN ... ON ... ON` is perfectly valid SQL syntax, just hardly used :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your from clause is not the typical way to write the `join`s.  It is allowed, but this affects the scoping of the identifiers.  Essentially, this is interpreted as:

```
from THB_View.PCM_PCM_BASE base left join
     (THB_View.PCM_PCM_BASE_REOCCUR rec left join
      THB_View.ATV atv
      on base.PCM_TAG = atv.ATV_OCCURRING_PCM_TAG
     )
     on base.RECORD_KEY = rec.RECORD_KEY
```

Which explains why `base` is not recognized.

Just write the `join`s the standard way with the `on` condition right after the tables being `join`ed:

```
from THB_View.PCM_PCM_BASE base left join
     THB_View.PCM_PCM_BASE_REOCCUR rec 
     on base.RECORD_KEY = rec.RECORD_KEY left join
     THB_View.ATV atv
     on base.PCM_TAG = atv.ATV_OCCURRING_PCM_TAG
```

Comment: Thanks, I was at the end of a long day and being pretty careless, I should have caught that before posting. I appreciate the response